# MongoDB Query Collection

Tags: database, mongodb, collections

I would like to querymy mongodb collection just like this SQl Query:

```sql
SELECT m1.stage_id, m2.stage_id
FROM Memories m1, Memories m2
WHERE m1.experience_id = m2.experience_id
AND m1.stage_id < m2.stage_id;
```

I want to have pairs of stage_id's at the end so I can input them in a CSV-File
[example of an document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fk8o.png)

Comment: Good practice is to add example documents as json/text ( not as pictures ) , also your SQL query looks like JOIN between m1 and m2 tables , good to provide examples from your mongoDB collections m1 and m2 and the expected result ... , to give you a hint you can use $lookup stage in mongoDB aggregation framework to achieve the same task as your SQL query ...

Comment: Welcome! [Programming language translation is generally too broad to be on-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296126/11107541). Please read the exceptions to learn what kind of translation questions you can ask here.